# What are the ways to create a custom shape touch detection?

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath

Hi I'm making a baseball app and I want from users to input strike zone on a grid like this:
[image]
How can I build the visual part so that I won't have too much trouble with implementation of a tap gesture recogniser. It'll be great if I can make this resizable so it will look great on many different devices.

With the touch gesture I need to handle so kind of recognizing position in two ways.

1. In which section the touch was detected.
2. What are the approximate coordinates inside this section.

This data will be saved on a cloud and can be later used to show the dot on this grid on other devices.

Is there a way to detect touch in a non rectangular shapes? Maybe with Bezier Paths.

Do you have a suggestion how ti appear on screen without using whole grid as a image. I'd rather divide it in Outer grid and the Inner grid somehow and than create all the pieces in each of this grids. 8 pieces in outer and 9 in inner grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with `UIBezierPath` and its method `containsPoint:`, although this method "does not take into account the line width used to stroke the path." ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBezierPath/containsPoint:)), it is also true for UIBezierPath.
Refer further to [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/cgpath-hit-testing/) article.